# conda update conda fails: nothing happens except a useless message

Tags: anaconda

Any attempt to upgrade `conda` gives:

```
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.7.12

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

without any other effect (and finally `conda` is never updated).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that one package (`lmfit`, I don't know why) is in conflict with 4.7.12 while no message/info is given. To get a piece of info, I asked explicitly to install 4.7.12:

```
conda install conda=4.7.12
```

then I get:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - conda=4.7.12
  - lmfit
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

when I try `conda info lmfit`, nothing happens...